# Is it possible to create custom Street View Panorama with "move" effect? How?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-street-view

The standard Google Street View Panorama on the https://www.google.com/maps looks like [this](https://www.google.com/maps/@48.865662,2.321717,3a,75y,149.52h,91.09t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sr5KSlvuvIlFtyYY59svoLA!2e0?hl=en).
When we click somewhere on the road, we'll go there with the "move" (or "slide") effect.

But when I try to add Google Street View Panorama to my site using Google Maps JavaScript API v3, I don't get this movement effect, just images change when I click on the road, without any effect.
Is there a way to obtain such effect using Google Maps JavaScript API?

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing documented anyway.

- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewPanorama